# Oracle given column names

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables with 2 columns (user_id and year).

Query1:

```
SELECT * FROM table_1 t1 
FULL JOIN table_2 t2 ON t1.user_id=t2.user_id AND t1.year=t2.year
```

Produces following column names:

```
user_id, year, user_id_1, year_1
```

Query2:

```
CREATE TABLE table_copy AS SELECT * FROM
(SELECT * FROM table_1 t1 
 FULL JOIN table_2 t2 ON t1.user_id=t2.user_id  AND t1.year=t2.year);
```

Produces following vague column names:

```
QCSJ_C000000000400000, QCSJ_C000000000400002, QCSJ_C000000000400001, QCSJ_C000000000400003
```

Is there a short way to force Oracle `query2` to use the same names as `query1` without writing them explicitly (it is important when there are many columns)? Maybe some Oracle settings?

Comment: You should always state your columns explicitly. There's no compelling reason not to.

Comment: You can write a query that will include the user_id column & year column from *only* 1 of the either table to avoid extra data (due to extra columns) getting filled in the destination table.

Comment: My intention was to be lazy enough to do all the joins and then drop duplicating columns manually because there is less columns to drop than explicitly to state. Although I don't know how it impacts on row chaining and other physical parameters that comes up when adding or droping columns on existing table.

Answer (score 5):

List your columns and use AS to specify the column name.

e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE table_copy AS
SELECT t1.user_id AS t1_user_id,
       t1.year    AS t1_year,
       t2.user_id AS t2_user_id,
       t2.year    AS t2_year
FROM   table_1 t1
FULL   JOIN table_2 t2 ON t1.user_id=t2.user_id
AND    t1.year=t2.year;
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't fully understand your expected part but what I understood is you want all columns from table_1 or from table_2 only

if it is like this only you can use following query to create table ..

```
CREATE TABLE table_copy AS SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT t1.* FROM table_1 t1 FULL JOIN table_2 t2 
      ON t1.user_id=t2.user_id  
      AND t1.year=t2.year);
```

or if you want both table's column but with different name in sql then you have to follow query suggested by **cagcowboy**  only....

but you can create table with prefix like "t1_" in plsql without specify or write all column name..

Comment: I want all columns from both tables. Since foreign key columns as user_id and year are the same because joining both tables I dont want user_id and year to appear in select list two times as duplicate columns. The point of the topic was just to figure out if it is possible to use query1 column names in query2 when using SELECT * syntax. It seems that it is not possible and I need to use PLSQL concatenated select list string as previously done.